# How many ring homomorphisms are there from $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that $0_{12}$ must go to $0_4$ and $1_{12}$ must go to $1_4$ unless everything goes to $0$, but I'm not sure about the other elements. Right now, I think there are just two ring homomorphisms here: the zero homomorphism and k mod 12 to k mod 4.

Comment: Well, it's not the identity. But the map $\phi(k\pmod{12})=k\pmod4$ is a well-defined homomorphism.

Comment: That's what I meant. What would I call that?

Comment: I would call it a projection. When you learn about ideals, you'll find you're passing to a quotient ring, and this is quite like projection in topology/linear algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $f(1_{12}) = 1_4$, then $f(1_{12} + 1_{12}) = \ldots$.  But it's not the "identity" homomorphism if it's not one-to-one.

Comment: Is the identity homomorphism the thing that takes everything to the identity?

Comment: I think it is not one-to-one because $f(0_{12})=0_4$ as well as $f(4)=f(1_{12}+1_{12}+1_{12}+1_{12})=1_4+1_4+1_4+1_4=0_4$.